# Replace NaN Values with the Means of other Cols based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A    c   1.0
1    A    c   3.0
2    B    c   5.0
3    A    d   6.0
4    A    c   NaN
```

I am writing the following function:

```
replace_missing_with_conditional_mean(df, condition_cols, cols)
```

I want to to replace the missing values present in columns with labels in the list `cols`.

The value to be replaced is computed as the mean of the non missing values of the corresponding group. Groups are formed based on the values in the columns with labels in the list `condition_cols`.

When `replace_missing_with_conditional_mean(df, condition_cols=['Col1','Col2'], cols=['Col3'])` is applied to the above dataframe with arguments, it should yield:

```
 Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A    c   1.0
1    A    c   3.0
2    B    c   5.0
3    A    d   6.0
4    A    c   2.0
```

this is because the record on line 4 belongs to the group `A c` that has a mean of (1+3)/2 = 2.

I tried using  `df.fillna(df.groupby(condition_cols).transform('mean'))` but it is giving me the error

```
TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types
```

Comment: What about `df.groupby(condition_cols)['Col3'].transform('mean')`?

Comment: @DaniMesejo it did solve the TypeError issue but for some reason it doesn't fill the NaN values.

Comment: What are you expecting for multiple columns for `cols=['Col3']`?

Comment: @DaniMesejo The function should work for any number of column values. For example if ```cols = ['Col3','Col4']``` the function should look into ```conditional_cols``` and see that NaN value at Col3 has ```A c``` grouping, then it should look for the rows with the same groupings and take the mean value for them in Col3. Same should happen for Col4 but mean should be calculated for Col4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the function like this:

```
def replace_missing_with_conditional_mean(df, condition_cols, cols):
    s = df.groupby(condition_cols)[cols].transform('mean')
    return df.fillna(s.to_dict('series'))


res = replace_missing_with_conditional_mean(df, ['Col1', 'Col2'], ['Col3'])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A    c   1.0
1    A    c   3.0
2    B    c   5.0
3    A    d   6.0
4    A    c   2.0
```

Comment: You dont need to convert `s` to a dictionary, as `fillna` works with Series and dataframes as well